# Magic rotated checkerboard function made in python!

Tags: computer-puzzle, checkerboard

Here's a puzzle for all you python programmers out there:

I defined a function that goes like this:

```
def checkers(num):
    magic = [_____________________________________________________________]
    print('\n'.join(magic + magic[num-2::-1]))
```

Here are the results from calling the function with different numbers:

---

```
checkers(1)
```

Output:

```
_|
_|
```

---

```
checkers(2)
```

Output:

```
  _|  
_|_|_|
  _|
```

---

```
checkers(3)
```

Output:

```
    _|    
  _|_|_|  
_|_|_|_|_|
  _|_|_|  
    _|
```

---

```
checkers(4)
```

Output:

```
      _|      
    _|_|_|    
  _|_|_|_|_|  
_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
  _|_|_|_|_|  
    _|_|_|    
      _|
```

---

```
checkers(5)
```

Output:

```
        _|        
      _|_|_|      
    _|_|_|_|_|    
  _|_|_|_|_|_|_|  
_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
  _|_|_|_|_|_|_|  
    _|_|_|_|_|    
      _|_|_|      
        _|
```

I hope you get the gist as to what the function does, but if not:

*Whatever number we pass into the brackets, it will print out a checker board rotated 45 degrees, with the number we passed in as each of its dimensions.*

**For your challenge, find out how `magic` is defined.**

You don't have to define it the same way I did, but just for a little hint on *one* way to define it, each underscore between the two square-brackets represents a character, with no unnecessary whitespaces (*I do love PEP-8, don't get me wrong*).

Comment: Are the trailing whitespaces on each row significant?

Comment: The 1x1 checkerboard usually has fewer than two squares though.

Comment: @Bubbler The trailing spaces were conclusive, but I guess I accidentally removed some from the last one. I'll add them in.

Comment: @Bass It is one square if you look at it sideways and squint really hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a fellow abuser of listcomps, magic is

> `"  "*(num-i-1)+"_|"*(2*i+1)+"  "*(num-i-1)for i in range(num)` 
>  It's a list of the rows in the upper half.

The hint is

> magic(1) not being square: this occurs because num-2 is -1 and so what would be all but the last row in reverse order becomes the last (and only) row

Answer (score 5):

49 bytes, respecting the spaces on the right side:

> ```
> ('_|'*(2*i+1)).center(num*4-2)for i in range(num)
> ```
>
> [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BCoMwFET3nuLvkh@JkLSFEvAkVoqkUdPiN6TpotC7p1ZBOqtZvHkT3mmc6XAOMeeb68GOzj5cfHJ6TWgKWDJ1g7dQQ8PZ9cME18KXCrGyjpKLP1AcpcZ@juDBE8SOBrfu23UfoqfE2YVYdZ898c1Xbt5m4aQ2RqoWMe/vCou9679@wvwF)

That said, it isn't a *very* interesting puzzle since string formatting tasks are common in regular programming, except the bit of inferring what the `magic` should evaluate to. I hope you come up with more interesting ones later :)